# Induced homomorphism of continuous injective/surjective map is injective/surjective.

Tags: general-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm really struggling with following exercise:

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a continuous map between topological space. Let $f_*:\pi_1(X,x) \to \pi_1(Y,f(x))$ be the induced homomorphism between the fundamental groups. Prove/disprove:

1. If $f$ is injective, then $f_*$ is injective.
2. If $f$ is surjective, then $f_*$ is surjective.

I'm not even sure how to begin with the first question, but I might have a start for the second question - Take the function $f: [0,1] \to S^1$, $f(t) = (\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t))$ which is surjective and the path $\gamma : [0,1] \to S^1$, $\gamma = f$. Choose $x = 0, f(x)=(0,1)$.  If $f \circ \delta \sim \gamma$ for some $\delta:[0,1] \to [0,1]$, since $\gamma = f$ we will have $f \circ \delta \sim f$. I'm not really sure how to proceed from here  - I think the issue will arise from either $\delta$ being a closed path or $S^1$ not being simply-connected, but I'm not sure.

Comment: For the first one, consider the inclusion of the circle in the disk. For the second one, consider the quotient map of the interval to the circle.

Comment: Your example is on  a good track already. Do you know what $\pi_1([0,1])$ and $\pi_1(S^1)$ are? Then, could $f_{\ast}$ possibly be surjective?

Comment: @Thorgott Could you elaborate on $\pi_1([0,1])$ and $\pi_1(S^1)$? And why $f_*$ could not be surjecitve? Does it have anything to do with the cardinalities of $[0,1]$ and $S^1$?

Comment: If you don't know how to calculate the fundamental groups of $[0,1]$ or $S^1$, I suggest you start reviewing your lectures/textbook there, because it is necessary to understand and has no doubt been covered. The other considerations can follow after.

Comment: @Thorgott So after doing some reviewing I now know $\pi_1(S^1,(1,0))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, and $\pi_1([0,1])$ is trivial since $[0,1]$ is simply-connected. Please tell me if I'm wrong here: If $f_*$ were surjective, we would have $|\pi_1([0,1])| \geq |\pi_1(S^1,(1,0))|$, but $|\pi_1([0,1])| = 1$ and $|\pi_1(S^1,(1,0))| = |\mathbb Z|$. Is there a more "topological" explaination other than considering the cardinalities?

Comment: Your argument is correct. I don't think you need a topological explanation for the elementary fact that the trivial group can't surject onto a non-trivial group. If you mean a topological explanation for why the surjectivity of $f$ doesn't imply the surjectivity of $f_{\ast}$, that's fair. Essentially, and the example illustrates this, surjectivity of $f_{\ast}$ means that you can lift loops (up to homotopy) through $f$ as loops. If you try to lift the loop going around $S^1$ once through our $f$, however, the result is the path traversing $[0,1]$ once, which is not a loop.